# using nameof() to inspect class name with its parent for MVC validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm attempting to add an error to the ModelState by using nameof:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo.Bar)
```

In the view, this has been tagged with a `name` of `Foo.Bar`.

When I add a model state error, I have to key that error to a `name`, so I use `nameof(Foo.Bar)` - however this just gives me `Bar`, when I need `Foo.Bar`.  Right now I can hardcode `Foo.Bar` but I'd rather use a strongly-typed method.  What are my options?

Comment: `nameof(Foo) + "." + nameof(Bar)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not built-in way to do that, but there are some workarounds.

You can concantenate names of the namespaces yourself (no runtime penalty, but hard to maintain):

```
String qualifiedName = String.Format("{0}.{1}", nameof(Foo), nameof(Bar));
```

Another option is to use reflecton to get the fully qualified name directly (easier, but has some runtime penalty):

```
String qualifiedName = typeof(Foo.Bar).FullName;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use expression trees.
You can have your own **ValidationMessageFor** extension method.
Check my **NameOf** method in the following example

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Name
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public MyClass Foo { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new MyClass().NameOf(m => m.MyProperty));//MyProperty
            Console.WriteLine(new MyClass().NameOf(m => m.Foo.MyProperty));//Foo.MyProperty
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class MyExtentions
    {
        public static string NameOf<T, TProperty>(this T t, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expr)
        {
            return string.Join(".", expr.ToString().Split('.').Skip(1));
        }
    }
}
```